# Observing other application window state changes on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have some application which captures content of other windows on OS X.
In regular intervals frame is captured. When window is minimized capturing thread is paused.

Now how to detect if window was restored? I like to avoid poling. Can I register some observer on third party application window state changes (maximize/minimize/restore)?

I didn't found anything useful in documentation of Quartz Window Services and I like to avoid polling.

Answer (score 0):

Try the notifications for [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification). There's no specific one for (de-)minimizing, but I suspect `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` might be useful for you.